# maven compiles tag files

Tags: maven, plugins, compilation

I am using maven-jspc-plugin to compile tag files

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jspc-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.8</version>
```

however, above plugin is only able to compile .jsp or .jspx file, not .tag

Anyone know which plugin allow .tag files compiled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jetty-jspc-maven-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-jspc-maven-plugin.html).

In their documentation they have the following property:

*`webAppSourceDirectory` - Root of resources directory where jsps, tags etc are located.*

So this certainly suggests that they can deal with tags. You will probably need to configure the `includes` property to include `.tag` files as its default value is `**/*.jsp, **/*.jspx`.

So something along the following lines:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jspc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jspc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/*.tag, **/*.jsp, **/*.jspx</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @Son Chau is usin Apache Tomcat and you suggested a jetty solution

Comment: @Zarathustra, at what point does Son Chau say they are using tomcat? In their question they specifically ask for a **maven** plugin that is capable of compiling .tag files, and I have suggested such a plugin that is able to do this.